# swift 3 conversion causing (lldb) error `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP,subcode)=0x0`

Tags: ios, swift3, comparator, lldb, xcode8

after converting my code for swift 3 i'm getting an error :

```
noteObjects.sort (comparator: { (first : AnyObject, second : AnyObject) -> ComparisonResult in

            if  let f : String = (first as! RChannels).name!   {
            let s : String = (second as! RChannels).name!

                return f.compare(s)
            }

        } as! (Any, Any) -> ComparisonResult)  // error here
```

this line `as! (Any, Any) -> ComparisonResult)` is giving me an error which says (lldb) without any other descriptions anyone can explain what is wrong here ??  and before conversion it was like this :

```
noteObjects.sortUsingComparator { (first : AnyObject, second : AnyObject) -> NSComparisonResult in
        if  let f : String = (first as! RChannels).name!   {
            let s : String = (second as! RChannels).name!
            return f.compare(s)
        }
     }
```

`noteObjects` is a NSMutableArray

Comment: Why that cumbersome comparator and `NSMutableArray`? Native Swift array type and sort function is much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `as! (Any, Any) -> ComparisonResult` and change the two parameters to `Any` instead of `AnyObject`.

```
noteObjects.sort(comparator: { (first : Any, second : Any) -> ComparisonResult in
    if let f : String = (first as! RChannels).name! {
        let s : String = (second as! RChannels).name!

        return f.compare(s)
    }
})
```

But that still has a few issues. You don't have a `return` value for every code path and you are not properly dealing with optionals. The following would be better:

```
noteObjects.sort(comparator: { (first : Any, second : Any) -> ComparisonResult in
    if let f = (first as! RChannels).name, let s = (second as! RChannels).name {
        return f.compare(s)
    } else {
        return .orderedSame
    }
})
```